# Pandas groupby each group and divide each row by its sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a','b','b','c','c','c'], 'score':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

group score
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   b   3
3   b   4
4   c   5
5   c   6
6   c   7
```

I want to divide each row by the sum of its group. So for group a, each of the 2 rows will divide by 3 (2+1), for group c, each of the 3 rows will divide by 18 (5+6+7), giving:

```
group score
0   a   0.33
1   a   0.67
2   b   0.43
3   b   0.57
4   c   0.28
5   c   0.33
6   c   0.39
```

I was thinking of using a `df.groupby('group')['score'].apply(lambda x: x / sum???)` approach but can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `df['score']/df.groupby('group')['score'].transform('sum')`

Comment: @QuangHoang do post as answer since I was about to post the same but u already commented. thanks

Comment: @AkshaySehgal This surely has a duplicate somewhere on SO, so I wouldn't post an answer :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah I thought there might be a solution somewhere on SO, but can't seem to find it!

Comment: It's surprising that the recommended posts that show up when marking something duplicate are not that great and instead googling the problem shows the top SO posts directly :)

Comment: @AkshaySehgal You're correct, SO search is terrible. I never use it.